# How can I regex match a character only if not followed by a different character?

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

I have an array with CA, C, CB, CZ. I want an if statement to match only C, CB, CZ.

```
@array = ("CA", "C", "CB", "CZ");

foreach (@array) {
 if ($_ =~ m/^C|^C.&[^CA]) {
  print "true \n";
 }
}
```

This doesn't work, but I think it might be close. What perl regex expressions can I use to achieve my goal?

Comment: can you just use `C[^A]` ? https://regex101.com/r/tB1rR1/1

Comment: I didn't even know this kind of thing existed, thank you!!!

Comment: No problem. Posting as an answer for future.

Comment: Yes I can, but it doesn't seem to match just "C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is the following:

```
/^C[BZ]?\z/
```

If you actually want to match strings that start with "C", but where the "C" isn't followed by "A", then you want the following:

```
/^C(?!A)/
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you mix `^` and `\z` (instead of `^` and `$` or `\A` and `\z`?

Comment: @Benjamin W., Because `$` does the wrong thing, and why would I want to use `\A` instead of `^`?

Comment: From perlre: "The `\A` and `\Z` are just like `^` and `$`, except that they won't match multiple times when the `/m` modifier is used, while `^` and `$` will match at every internal line boundary. To match the actual end of the string and not ignore an optional trailing newline, use `\z`." I understand that you'd usually use `\A` and `\z` (or `\Z`) when dealing with multiline strings, and `^` and `$` when dealing with oneline strings. `/^.*\z/` matches the last line of a multiline string, but why use `\z` when the input is not multiline?

Comment: @Benjamin W., Again, because using `$` would give the wrong result. `$` is equivalent to `(?=\n?\z)`.

Comment: (or `(?=\n|\z)` with `/m`)

Comment: Please forgive my blindness, but I really don't see the difference. Both `/^C[BZ]?\z/` and `/^C[BZ]?$/` work for me. You say `$` is like a positive look-ahead for optional end-of-line and end-of-string, but how does that apply to the examples by the OP? (Also, sorry for spamming here, but the magic "move to chat" link hasn't appeared yet...)

Comment: @Benjamin W., `\n` doesn't match end-of-line, whatever that means. It matches a newline. Do any of the acceptable inputs include newlines?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you ask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
@array = ("CA", "C", "CB", "CZ");

foreach (@array) {
  if ($_ =~ m/^C$|^C[^A]/) {
    print "true \n";
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a long way of writing `/^C(?!A)/`, and it matches far more than what the OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following regex,

```
C[^A]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB1rR1/1)

Comment: I get exactly what I am try to do when I use `C[^A]|C$`

Comment: @Chemist not a Programmer , `C[^A]|C$` will match `ACZ`.